# how to fetch List of data from Postgres Database using Spring Batch

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am using spring batch to fetch, process and write some data. I am using Postgres. I want to fetch list of data instead of fetching data one by one and want to pass the same list to processor. Is this possible in Spring Batch?

Comment: Please use chunk size for that if chunk size is 10 then 10 records will be read from DB, processed and write to file.

Comment: i want to get all those 10 records in a single batch run .fetch 10 records in one go

Answer (score 0):

The chunk-oriented processing is designed to read one item at a time. Now how to define an "item" is up to you. If you think a "list of items" is one item then you can still use that model, but you would need a custom item reader that returns a list.

All item readers provided by Spring Batch are designed to return a single piece of data, like a line in a flat file, a record in database table, a document from a NoSQL collection, a message from a queue, a file in a folder, etc. Anything that deviates from that requires a custom item reader.